# Volume between two paraboloids (I think it misses some data)

Tags: definite-integrals, volume

I have to find the volume of the region bounded the two paraboloids:
$$z=x^{2}+y^{2}$$
and
$$z=4x^{2}+4y^{2}$$
and also limited by the cylinder 
$$y=x^{2}$$
and the plane
$$y=3x$$

I could draw this region in the space but, for me, there's no a maximum value for $z$. Since if $z=z$, then
$$4x^{2}+4y^{2}=x^{2}+y^{2}\Rightarrow x=y=0$$
So, the only intersection between the paraboloids is the origin $(0,0,0)$. I think that it misses some data, cause in this way, I think the region has no maximum value in $z$, then its volume is infinity.

Comment: Yes, the two paraboloids are only tangent to each other, but how do they intersect the other two surfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y=x^2, y = 3x$ form a closed region above the $xy$ plane, forming the "lateral" bounds of your volume.

The paraboloids form the vertical bounds.

$V=\int_0^3\int_{x^2}^{3x}\int_{x^2+y^2}^{4(x^2+y^2)}\ dz\ dy\ dx$

Comment: But it seems that this region has no end looking in the $z$ axis.

Comment: Give me a coordinate that is inside the region where $z = 500$ (or greater)?  If $z$ is that big, it must be outside the cylinder.